# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import './cart.dart';

class OrderItem {
 final String id;
  final double amount;
  final List<CartItem> products;
  final DateTime dateTime;

  OrderItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.amount,
    required this.products,
    required this.dateTime,
  });
}

class Orders with ChangeNotifier {
  List<OrderItem> _orders = [];

  List<OrderItem> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }
```

The errored block( when I do if check to null, vscode says The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false. also, I get an error saying Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in typecast.

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetOrders() async {
    final url =
        Uri.https('shopapp-63-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com', '/orders.json');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    final List<OrderItem> loadedOrders = [];
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (extractedData == null) {
      return;
    }

    extractedData.forEach((orderId, orderData) {
      loadedOrders.add(
        OrderItem(
          id: orderId,
          amount: orderData['amount'],
          dateTime: DateTime.parse(orderData['dateTime']),
          products: (orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>)
              .map((item) => CartItem(
                    id: item['id'],
                    title: item['title'],
                    quantity: item['quantity'],
                    price: item['price'],
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      );
    });
    _orders = loadedOrders;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using Flutter 2.0+ which has nullsafety.
Thus you can not check for a `null` to a variable which you do not define nullable explicitly.

Try defining

```dart
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData = json.de...
```

as

```dart
    final response? = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData? = json....
```

to slove  `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false`
Then you can check null using `??` operator or with the if condition you are already using.

I don't know why `null` is not a subtype of type `Map<String, dynamic>` is occurring. Because your `http.get(url)` should not return `null` by any means.

Comment: when I add those question marks it shows a red line underneath wherever I use 'response' and 'extractedData' and it says The final variable 'response' can't be read because it is potentially unassigned at this point.
Ensure that it is assigned on necessary execution

Comment: If you are now sure that your response is not NULL. then try accessing that variable using '!' at the end. Example. response!

Comment: The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null.
Try removing the '!' operator. the error i got

Answer (score 2):

try this method instead.

```
{
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final _data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (_data != null) {
        final extractedData = _data as Map<String, dynamic>;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is caused by nullsafety

try defining

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>
```

as

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>?
```